# How to calculate the area of a circle by integration between two functions

Tags: calculus, integration, circles

I am really lost on this problem I have been given in my math assignment and I have tried looking at all my notes and asking my teacher, but he doesn't have any more time to help me, so I will need the rest from you guys :)

Anyway, I am supposed to calculate the area of a plate of a kids' swing, which looks like this

[image: Swing]

**I have calculated everything else than the area shown here in red:**
[image: Remaining area]

And I was told the following by my teacher:

> Determine the function for the relevant circle peripheral pieces and
> determine, by integrating, the area between the graphs for two
> functions.

So I have to find the functions for the relevant curves that will give me the remaining area by doing the above. The thing is I don't know how to do it when I only know the points and the curves shown and I don't know if I can find it by using the circle's equation either.

So how do I do this? Like I said, I know all points and curves
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have the radius of the circle. I would calculate the area of the minor segment formed by points G and I using $\frac{r^2}{2}[\theta - \sin(\theta)]$ (in radians). Then find the point of intersection between the curve $LG$ and the vertical line intersecting M which we will call $\lambda$, we can then integrate the curve $LG$ between $\lambda$ and $G$ from which we will then remove the area below $MI$ by integrating under our circle between the two points! This can be done by integrating $y=-(r^2-(x-a)^2)^{0.5}-b$ for circle $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2$ between $M$ and $I$.

Hopefully I have explained the method well enough, if you need help with the computation just let me know!

Comment: I don't know how to use the first formula you mention, where do I get $\theta$ from? I've found the intersection between the curve $LG$  and the vertical line intersecting M. I can integrate from $\lambda$ to $G$ but I just don't know how to integrate the circle's equation or whatever I need to use for it.

Comment: You could use the line between $LI$ and the cosine rule to figure out $\theta$ and search how to find a segment in a circle to understand the formula better where $r$ is of course the radius and $\theta$ is as discussed. Integrating under the circle is the same as integrating under $LO$ between the negative of the x coordinates of $I$ and $M$.

Comment: If your interested into how to integrate under the circle without the knowledge of the other function I have added the equation for the bottom half of the circle :)